# TYPO3 and Composer-Commands

Tags: php, composer-php, typo3

short question about TYPO3 and Composer. After receiving the recommendation never to edit Composer.json manually, I would like to know how to automatically include additional VCS sources like Github. Surely there is a console command for this, isn't there? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, please see [**Modifying Repositories** in the Composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#modifying-repositories):

```
composer config repositories.foo vcs https://github.com/foo/bar
```